# How to create new JS array from an JS object

Tags: javascript

I want to create new JS array from an object. I explained my scenario as below.

obj1

```
obj1 = {
  MMJ_KKL: {CODE: "SSW", YARN: 4500, WARN: "NBVC"},
  KKN_AAS: {CODE: "NNH", YARN: 1540, WARN: "MHYT"},
  LLK_PPO: {CODE: "KKI", YARN: 2312, WARN: "POIU"}
}
```

obj2

```
obj2 = {
  MMJ_KKL:{CODE: "SSW", YARN: 2300, WARN: "NBVC"},
  KKN_AAS:{CODE: "NNH", YARN: 3329, WARN: "MHYT"},
  LLK_PPO:{CODE: "KKI", YARN: 2312, WARN: "POIU"},
  RRE_WED:{CODE: "QQA", YARN: 4430, WARN: "IUYT"}
}
```

Now you all can see there is a change between obj1 and obj2. they are,

- obj1.MMJ_KKL.YARN and obj2.MMJ_KKL.YARN
- obj1.KKN_AAS.YARN and obj2.KKN_AAS.YARN
  Now it needs to create new array and put it the changed values.

******Note: we can not consider here RRE_WED in obj2. Because such value is not contained in obj1.

Tried code:

```
Object.keys(obj2).forEach((item) =>
    const result = obj1.filter((item) => arr1[item.code] && !(obj2[item.product_code].YARN === item.YARN && obj2[item.WARN].note === item.WARN));
);
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "CODE": "SSW",
    "YARN": "2300",
    "WARN": "NBVC"
  },
  {
    "CODE": "NNH",
    "YARN": "3329",
    "WARN": "MHYT"
  }
]
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `arr1` and `arr2` are not arrays.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder they are objects. I am complete new to JS. Please sorry for my terminology.

Comment: Your code loops through creating a new array every time (via `filter`) and then just throwing it away by not doing anything with it. You might want `map` rather than `forEach`, but it's hard to tell what you're doing here...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am doing here, compare `obj1` and `obj2`. Then check `YARN ` are similar or not. If there is a difference it should create new array as I mention in quection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand all the criteria you want to use, but this will give you the expected output.

```
Object.keys(obj1)
  .filter(key => Boolean(obj2[key]))
  .filter(key => obj1[key].YARN !== obj2[key].YARN)
  .map(key => obj2[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you want to merge obj2 to obj1:

1 - Use `stringify` to find attributes that have the changes. 
2 - Use spread operator `...` to merge obj2 to obj1.

```
Object.keys(obj1)
    .filter((k)=>JSON.stringify(obj1[k]) !== JSON.stringify(obj2[k]))
    .map((k)=> ({...obj1[k], ...obj2[k]}))
```